# How do i add another field to Django's default user model. For instance, adding a field called matricule

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a project where by users needs to use their matricules and password as a form of authentication. Please how do i go about adding a matricule to Django's default user model

Comment: Try using custom django user model. please check this link for your reference https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-django-user-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the default User model.

in your `models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NewUser(User):
    matricules = models.Charfield(max_length=30)
    #add other fields here
```